# Content script loading images from an extension ( CSP )

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, content-security-policy, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a browser extension both for chrome & firefox.

My content script injects (only in twitter) some new images hosted from another server.

Here is a basic example of what am I doing :

```
fetch('mysite.com')
    .then(data => {
         let imgTag = document.createElement('img');
         imgTag.src = data.url; // (https://example.com/image.jpg)
         div.appendChild(imgTag);
    });
```

It works on chrome but not in firefox, the console is showing a Content Security Policy related error, it simply says that the CSP rules that are applied on twitter doesn't allow for my hosted images to load.

What bugs me is why it is working on chrome just fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundle the images with your extension. Extension URLs (`moz-extension://`) are exempt from CSP.

If you need dynamic content then you'll have to wait until issue [1294996](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1294996) or [1267027](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1267027) gets implemented.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, so It is indeed impossible for the moment.